# ChromeDriver select multiple word class name

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to access an element with ChromeDriver using `SelectElementByClassName`.

```
driver.FindElementByClassName("ou selected");
```

The element's class is : `ou selected` but I cannot use this method because I get the :

```
Compound class name not permitted exception
```

Is it impossible for me to select all these classes ? 
Is there a possible work around ?

---

Even with the CSS selection, I get another error which says "no such element". 
The element exists :

> [image]

It needs a few milliseconds to load but still so I added a Timeout to make sure it loads properly. Still, I get the same error. Here is the code :

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
driver.FindElementByCssSelector(".ou.selected").SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `FindElementByCssSelector`, not `FindElementByClassName` in this situation.  ByClassName, as it states, does not support compound classes.  This is why you use a CSS selector to match on the classes you want.

```
driver.FindElementByCssSelector(".ou.selected")
```

#### Edit

Looks like you want to select the link?  If so, then you need -

```
driver.FindElementByCssSelector("span.ou.selected > a")
```

Comment: no, i'm just an experienced selenium user and contributor `:)`  and i'm glad my answer helped!

Comment: Thanks @sircapsalot it helped me :)